# Foreach checked checkbox do quicksand jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, sorting, quicksand

Based on http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/ tutorial I am trying to implement a sort function to my app.

The problem:

I have the items that I will sort later with quicksand jquery plugin in this format:

```
<ul>
<li class="car">Audi A6</li>
<li class="car">Audi A8</li>
<li class="car">BMW 328Ci</li>
<li class="hobby">Skying</li>
<li class="hobby">Skating</li>
<li class="hobby">Running</li>
<li class="food">Pizza</li>
<li class="food">Salat</li>
<li class="food">Chicken</li>
</ul>
```

and then I have 3 checkboxes to be used to sort what to show and what to not:

```
    <ul id="filter_sources">
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="source" value="car" />car</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="source" value="hobby" />hobby</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="source" value="food" />food</li>
    </ul>
```

What I want to do is that for each checked checkbox run the quicksand plugin and show the checked boxes, so if the **car** and **hobby** checkboxes are checked to show car and hobby lists

I am asking this because in the tutorial they do it this way:

```
$('#filter_sources').live('click',function(e){
        var link = $(this);

        link.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        // Using the Quicksand plugin to animate the li items.
        // It uses data('list') defined by our createList function:

        $('#videosList').quicksand(link.data('list').find('li'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

and I did some attempts to try for each checked input but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested and, demonstrably, working:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        var show = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
                           return $(this).val();
                   });
        console.log(show);
        $('#list li').each(
            function(){
                if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) > -1) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ck8Nr/).

Note that, for the sake of simplicity, and to avoid the `not()` method, I opted to assign an `id` to the list containing the elements to be filtered.

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP:

> [Only] one problem, when you deselect all the checkboxes after selecting any of them all the results vanishes...

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        var show = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
                           return $(this).val();
                   });
        if (show.length > 0){
            $('#list li').each(
                function(){
                    if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) > -1) {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            $('#list li').show();
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ck8Nr/1/).
References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/array/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).
- [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inArray/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: only one problem, when you deselect all the checkboxes after selecting any of them all the results vanishes :D

Comment: Well, yes. What would your preferred option be, if there was nothing checked? No filtering at all, I'm guessing?

Comment: no, if none checked it needs to show all of the lists results

Comment: Edited the answer to check for filtering and, if there is no filtering selected, amended to show the whole list.

Comment: amaHAZING :). Thank you very much and wish you a very great year and prosperous

Comment: Well, thank you kindly! And I'm glad to have been of help, thank you for the accept and the up-vote (assuming they're both yours, obviously) =D

Comment: yes they are David, but I have come back to ask you if you could explain what the **> -1** at `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) > -1)` because I need to add an if only 1 checkbox is selected show something else

Comment: I have some issues... I need to check if only 1 checkbox is selected and it keeps giving me problems when trying with `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) == 0){}` because I want that if 1 checkbox is checked to do a `if($(this).attr('class') == 'box') ... ` . Am I checking it the right way for if only 1 checkbox?